# PROC SQL, can't filter datepart between date converted from numeric

Tags: date, sas, proc-sql

I have a SAS table `sastable` that I'm joining with a column from a SQL database to create  a new table. However, I need to filter the `sql.data` with a date column from `sastable`. `sastable.date` is already in date time format, but `sql.start` and `sql.end` are stored in numeric YYYYMMDD format, such as '20231219'.

My code currently looks like this:

```
Proc sql;
Create Table newtable as
Select a.*,
   b.sqldate
From sastable as a
Left Join sql as b on a.id=b.id
where (datepart(a.date) between input(put(b.start, yymmdd10.),yymmdd10.) 
   and input(put(b.end, yymmdd10.), yymmdd10.)) 
   and b.void = '';
```

When run, the table comes up empty. Any guidance on how to fix this would be appreciated. Or if I'm not even on the right track.

Comment: Do the variables in the SQL dataset have DATE values? Or are they just numbers like 20,231,219? Or are they character strings with values like '20231219'?  Or perhaps the SQL dataset has DATETIME values that are just displaying without the time of day part?

Comment: If A.DATE has date values and not datetime values then applying DATETIME() function to it will return zero since there are 86,400 seconds in a single day.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "but 'sql.start' and 'sql.end' are stored in numeric YYYYMMDD format" it makes no sense since SAS dates are just numbers.
If it is the case, a Date, then no need to input and put.
If not, the storage format is not what you think.
To make it simple: if start and end are dates (no importance what informat and format are), your code become:
datepart(a.date) between b.start and b.end

Comment: Tom answer is the good one if your columns START and END are numeric with date content, eg 20231219 . The Z8. will convert into text then the informat will read them back into SAS dates.

Answer (score 0):

If START and END have integer values like 20,231,219 then you need to use the Z8. or plain old 8. format to convert them into strings that the YYMMDD8. informat can read.

```
input(put(b.end, Z8.), yymmdd8.)
```

Comment: START and END have values such as 20231219 for todays date. Sorry for the confusion. That's why I used the YYMMDD10. I updated with what you provided just in case and the table still came up blank.

Comment: Copy example values for START and END from the SQL "table" into a SAS dataset and print the values using the BEST32. format.  If the value is DATE then today's date will print as 23363.  If it is a datetime value it will be much larger, like 2018605241.818.  If it is character you will get an error that $BEST format cannot be found.